# Can i run another docker as services?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have two docker images in Nexus repo

```
1. sql-db
2. main-svc
```

The `main-svc` need `sql-db` in order to run completely.

Can I defined such in `gitlab-ci.yml`?

```
Build:
 image: test.com/main-svc:1.5
 services: test.com/sql-db:1.0
 script:
   - docker pull test.com/main-svc:1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use docker-in-docker, but you don't need to. Simply define two service containers, as such:

```
build:
  image: alpine
  services:
    - postgres:latest
    - redis:latest
  script:
    - echo "hello world"
```

I didn't edit your example because I'm a bit confused about why you're using the same container for both the `image` and the `docker pull` inside it. My guess is you have a container you're trying to run integration tests with, then you're testing a container which needs to connect to a database as two different services. If not, it would be helpful for you to state what problem you're trying to solve and we can help more.

Comment: Ok i see that i actually do not need the pull script. I have trivy scanner docker (main svc) and its vulnerability databse (db) in another docker. The database need to be up first then the main svc can get data from db. Perhaps i need to do copy the d  docker content to main svc docker in this case. Not sure what is the right way.